# Are there any problems that require exponential time in quantum computing?

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-computing

Given the fact that the qbits have superpositions, and have more representational power compared to circuits, are there any problems that require at least exponential time to guarantee a solution with a quantum computer?

I've checked the [Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo) and couldn't find any complexity class mentioned there that fits this description.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most problems that require exponential time on a classical computer also require exponential time on a quantum computer.  For example EXPTIME-complete problems will require exponential time on either a classical or a quantum computer.

The class of problems solvable in polynomial time on a quantum computer is called BQP.  It is believed unlikely that BQP contains the NP-complete problems.  Thus the NP-complete problems probably take exponential time on quantum computers.

One of the most interesting problems that is known to be in BQP, but believed not to be in P is the integer factoring problem.  But integer factoring is believed unlikely to be NP-complete.